# Python p5250 library - open wc3270 connection with 27x132 screen size

Tags: python, automation, screen-size

Generally, I want to automate my work in IBM i emulator with `Python`. I use [p5250](https://github.com/simonfaltum/p5250) library which use [wc3270](https://x3270.miraheze.org/wiki/Main_Page) to connect to my server. Everything works fine until my host needs to oversize the screen to 27x132.

1. First view to log in is 24x80 [rowsXcolumns] size.
2. After login, host must be 27x132 on main menu.

Question - is there any solution to run object `P5250Client` with 27x132 screen size?

My code:

```
from p5250 import P5250Client

session = P5250Client(modelName='3278-5', hostName='hostName', path='c:\\Program Files\\wc3270\\', codePage='cp273')

session.connect()

# ...
```

I tried to change `modelName` to other emulation types [IBM - emulation types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=problems-troubleshooting-emulation-types) (e.g. modelName='3180-5') but none with 27x132 emulator works in `p5250` library.

Comment: I was going to suggest reporting an issue / asking for support to the project itself... but it looks like that "library" is one person's pet project with only 5 commits and no activity for the last _3 years_. I'd strongly avoid it entirely, unless you want to take over maintenance of a fork.